# How to make flash as header background

Tags: html, flash

I have read so many tutorials about make flash as background of a header, but there are several code involved on there. Can you explain to me how to make flash as background?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two div's that are exactly on the same place. Then you put your flash content in div 1 and your content you want "on top" in div 2.

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="flash_header_background">FLASH HERE</div>
    <div id="header_foreground">CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>
```

Then you style your div's with CSS to they are on top of each other.

```
#holder {
    height: 250px; /* Flash height */
    width: 800px; /* Flash width */
    position: relative;
}

#flash_header_background {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#header_foreground {
    z-index: 2; /* Puts this div above the background DIV */
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** Remember to set the `wmode` of your flash content to `opaque` or `transparent`. - Thank you strah for reminding

Comment: And remember to set the wmode to opaque or transparent.

Comment: I have follow your instruction, but it only show on certain chrome, and other browser is not, how to solve? my site is http://www.threelas.com

Comment: I have tried it in: Safari, Google Chrome and Firefox. They all work fine. I have edited my post, so try the new CSS.

Answer (score 1):

The single most important element involved in making flash media a background (i.e. being able to place stuff ontop of it) is to ensure that when embedding, you're setting the `wmode` to `opaque` or `transparent`. Failing to do so will mean that no matter what, the media will render ontop of the other elements on the page.

Other than that, you just need to use CSS to place content over the media via `position: absolute;` and possibly allocating a higher value for `z-index`.